# Use And and or operator together in sql

Tags: sql, db2

Is there any way that i could use and and like operator with or to get desired

Select * from table where column1 = 1 and column2 =10 and column3 like '%we%' or column3 like '%ws%'

Need to use or in just 3rd column but with and of other 3 Columns

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select * from table where column1 = 1 and column2 =10 and (column3 like '%we%' or column3 like '%ws%');
```

That's how you can get your desired output.

Comment: I tried but it fetch all records of column 1 , 2 ,3